# Не работает LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Пытаюсь обновить таблицу с помощью LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, чтобы лочилось, когда обновляешь с разных сайтов старые значения. Обновляется так же, как и без локмода

```
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            int idCity = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idCity"));
            city.setIdCity(idCity);
            try {

               City city = (City) 
                       session.get(City.class, idCity, 
                                   new LockOptions(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE));

               if (!cityName.equals(city.getCityName())) {


                 city.setCityName(cityName);
                 session.update(city);

                 transaction.commit();
               } else {
                 transaction.rollback();
               }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (transaction!=null) transaction.rollback();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            finally{
                session.close();
            }
```